# Remove WPML's home_url filter

Tags: filters, plugin-wpml, home-url

The WPML plugin filter's `home_url` in order to provide a link to the home page specific to the language you are viewing. (So if you are reading a Spanish page home_url() will point you to `http://example.com/es`). I need to disable for a site that will not have language-specific homepages. So I went digging into the WPML plugin, which is essentially launched in a typical way:

```
global $sitepress;
$sitepress = new SitePress();
```

Then in the class's constructor the offending filter is added:

```
add_filter( 'home_url', array( $this, 'home_url' ), 1, 4 );
```

With the class's callback method being (for reference):

```
// filter for WP home_url function
function home_url( $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id )
{
    // exception for get_page_num_link and language_negotiation_type = 3
    if ( $this->settings[ 'language_negotiation_type' ] == 3 ) {
        $debug_backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        if ( !empty( $debug_backtrace[ 6 ] ) && $debug_backtrace[ 6 ][ 'function' ] == 'get_pagenum_link' )
            return $url;
    }

    remove_filter( 'home_url', array( $this, 'home_url' ), 1 );
    // only apply this for home url - not for posts or page permalinks since this filter is called there too
    if ( ( did_action( 'template_redirect' ) && rtrim( $url, '/' ) == rtrim( get_home_url(), '/' ) ) || $path == '/' ) {
        $url = $this->convert_url( $url );
    }
    add_filter( 'home_url', array( $this, 'home_url' ), 1, 4 );

    return $url;
}
```

This seems like it should be a straight-forward case of `remove_filter`. However adding the following to functions.php (admittedly it should maybe be in a site-specific plugin) does not seem to remove the filter and the main logo (which uses the `home_url()` function is still pointing to the language-specific homepage).

```
function rar_remove_wpml_home_filter(){
    global $sitepress;
    remove_filter( 'home_url', array( $sitepress, 'home_url' ), 1, 4 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'rar_remove_wpml_home_filter' );
```

I've also tried running this on the `init` hook. It seems I must me missing something obvious.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140567/disable-home-url-rewrite-with-wpml-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it required removing 4 filters/actions to undo WPML's `home_url` modification. Since I didn't know what *else* this might break, I ended up changing my site's logo to use `site_url()` which in my case was the same, but not changed by WPML.

```
function disable_things(){
    remove_filter( 'page_link', array( $this, 'permalink_filter' ), 1, 2 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'front_end_js' ) );
    remove_filter( 'feed_link', array( $this, 'feed_link' ) );
    remove_filter( 'home_url', array( $this, 'home_url' ), 1, 4 );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'disable_things', 20 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. Used WPML filter and returned default url rather than filtered one.

```
function custom_wpml_home_url( $home_url, $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id ) {
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpml_get_home_url', 'custom_wpml_home_url', 99, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about taking a different approach?

Keep the filter and in WPML -> Languages, chose "Use directory for default language".

There you can specify a static file or create a "Root page".

This page won't be connected to any language. 
It won't even show the language switcher (unless you use a custom template and play with the code).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_option( 'home' );`

It will give you back blog’s home web address set in General Options.